# Binary Matrix shifting and matching

Tags: c++, matrix, matching

I have two binaries matrices. I want to compare these two matrices and find the maximum matching by shifting rows up and down and shifting columns right and left. For example: I have matrix `a= [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 0 1 1] and matrix b = [ 1 0 1; 0 1 0; 1 0 1]` The matching here is three numbers. If I shift matrix a to the right by one, matrix a will be: `a = [0 1 1; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]. if I shift it by two: a = [0 0 1 ; 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 ].` You can see there is a column of zeroes added to the left. This will be applied to all types of shifting in all directions. I wrote the following code to count how many matched numbers (same ones at the same location - we don't care about zeroes) between a and b.

```
int i, j;
int count=0;
int max = 0;

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(a[i][j] == 1 && b[i][j] == 1){
                cout << "Element found at (" << i << ", "<< j << ")"<<endl;
                count++;
                max = count;
                }
        }
    } cout <<max <<endl;
```

Now, I want to take the max from the above code and perform shifting on matrix a and compare the new matching count with my previous max. I want to shift one by one until I hit the maximum matching. Something like this:

```
if(new_count<max && shift<matrix_size){
  ///Shifting to the right
  for(i=0; i<m; i++){
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        //new_a[i][j] = new_a[i][j+shift];
        cout << new_a[i][j]<<" ";
        count++;
    }
  } cout<<endl;
  shift++;

} else{
    cout <<" The maximum matching is: "<<max<<endl;
}

  ///Shifting to the left
  for(i=0; i<m; i++){
    for(j=n-1; j>=0; j++){
        //new_a[i][j] = new_a[i][j-shift];
        cout << new_a[i][j]<<" ";
        count++;
    }
  } cout<<endl;
  shift++;

} else{
    cout <<" The maximum matching is: "<<max<<endl;
}


///Shifting up


///Shifting down
```

I'm stuck in the last part. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you write tests for it? If not you should start from this. Are you looking for optimal solution or you are fine with brutal force?

Comment: I want to test it for n*n. I didn't write any tests yet. I would really love to see the optimal solution. Thanks, @MarekR for your reply.

Comment: Here are tests you can start with: https://godbolt.org/z/PvYd68fff add more test cases to `GENERATE`. Note also there is possible ambiguity, so definition is needed how to resolve it.

Comment: [small update](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4oYT8xjr).

Comment: You should use `template <std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols> using Matrix = std::array<cols, std::bitset<rows>>;` `bitset` has `<<`, `>>`, `&` and `count`. And you can use ranged-for and accumulate.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I'll try these solutions and suggestions and update you.

Answer (score 1):

**Refactor your code**

You already know how to compute matches, and you already know how to shift matrices, so you already have your solution. Let's first refactor the code you have into those two functions :

```
int computeMatches(const Matrix* a, const Matrix* b);

Matrix* computeShiftedMatrix(const Matrix* m, int shifting);
```

Please note that in `computeShiftedMatrix()` you need to return a new matrix that is the shifted copy of m, you don't change the original matrix.
Now the solution you are looking for is simply :

```
Matrix* a,b;
const int maxShift = 2; // put here how many shifts you want to try
int maximumMatchingShift = -1;
int maximumMatches = 0;
for (int i=0; i<maxShift; ++i)
{
  Matrix* shiftedA = computeShiftedMatrix(a, i);
  int currentMatches = computeMatches(shiftedA, b);
  if (currentMatches > maximumMatches)
  {
    maximumMatchingShift = i;
    maximumMatches = currentMatches;

  }
}
```

Now `maximumMatchingShift` holds the optimal shift with maximized matches.

Comment: Thanks Mickaël C. Guimarães for your reply. I'll try it out and let you know if I have any questions.